# SSO between ASP.Net MVC and Flex applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, apache-flex, single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

I have two applications. One is written in ASP.NET MVC and the other in Flex. We wanted to have a SSO between these two applications. Both of these applications share common user Database. From .NET-side I can use thinktecture but I'm not sure if Flex is supported.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

There a few as3 library that focus on interfacing with OAuth.

- https://github.com/charlesbihis/actionscript-oauth2
- https://github.com/iotashan/oauth-as3